# How to Read from a Text File into a List And Read from that list C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to Read from a Text File and then put each line into a list then read from that list. But I am getting a NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." In the while exception about 7 lines down. I have tried out everything I can think of. Thanks in advance.

```
                StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(FILE_PATH);
                Books books = new Books();
                string line;
                while ((line = sre.ReadToEnd()) != null)
                {
                 //NullReferenceException is Right here
                 //I defined myLibraryBooks outside of this code; But it is in the same scope
                    myLibraryBooks.Add(new Books() { Author = books.Author.ToUpper(), Title = line.ToUpper(), ISBN = line, Publish_Date = line });
                }
                Console.Write("Enter Author's Name:");
                string input_to_find = Console.ReadLine();
                var author = from Authors in myLibraryBooks
                             where Authors.Author == input_to_find
                             select Authors;

                foreach (var book in author)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("      Author            Title            ISBN            Publish Date"));
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("       {0}          {1}              {2}                {3}", books.Author, books.Title, books.ISBN, books.Publish_Date));
                }
                sre.Dispose();
```

Comment: You don't define `myLibraryBooks` in this code.  It's probably null.

Comment: or `books.Author` is null

Comment: Also `TextReader.ReadToEnd()` does not read a line - it reads to the end of the file.

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and use Visual Studio to check the value of each of your variables on that line to see which is null.

Comment: @mbeckish  I just did that and found it just stays in the while loop.

Comment: There is a lot going on at each iteration of the while loop.  You need to find the exact iteration that is throwing the error and then look at every single object that is in scope to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Ok I figured out that while loop problem... Thank you  ..... Now it won't read out to the Console Window.

Comment: Kyson you can read the file into a List<T> using one line of code and then iterate thru the list your example can be done in a much simpler fashion

Comment: Probably time to accept @AbeMiessler's answer, and post a new question if you are having a different problem.

Comment: Okay it's just a little thing In the Foreach loop instead of printing 1 time it prints 4 times.

Comment: One possible issue: you are referencing `books` instead of `book` in your loop.

Comment: Yes I changed that because before it wouldn't even print out and now it does that 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `books`, but it doesn't look like it is getting set to anything (unless you are doing some weird stuff in your constructor).  Based on this, I would say the following line could cause this exception:

```
      *Guessing Author is null...
books.Author.ToUpper()
```

Take advantage of .NET's debugging tools and step through your code line by line to see where the problem is.